Apache Nifi: Add property to Processor which accepts Sensitive Value
Within an Apache Nifi Workflow I would like to create a property which accepts a Sensitive Value.
Via #{password} I would like to assign a parameter from my context parameter to this custom property.
Unfortunately GenerateFlowFile does not allow to mark custom properties as sensitive.
Any help or hint, which Processor to use is highly appreciated.

So you don't want #{password} displayed?

Yes, I would Like to assign the value of my context parameter password, which is sensitiv, to a custom property..

If you are using Parameter Context, why not set the value as Sensitive there. Then you are just referring the parameter name in the Custom property created in the GenerateFlowFile.
